# Flot: How to find y coordinate on a line given the x coordinate

Tags: graph, flot, point, intersection

I am using a Flot graph and I am setting up various interactive elements.
One of these elements is one in which the user inputs any x value (It really could be either an x or y value depending on the situation, but for simplicity, let's assume it is always an x-axis value) and I need to output the corresponding y coordinate on the line I have graphed.  I feel like this should be kind of simple, so I apologize if the answer is an obvious one.  Note that the input value is probably not going to be a "point" in the array which flot is using to create the line (although it could).

You could also imagine a vertical line at x = [user input, not necessarily a whole number] intersecting another line series at some point.  I would need to find the point of intersection.  I tried uploading a photo, but I don't have enough reputation points.

Comment: What if you have two x values that are identical? Are both y values displayed?

Comment: The user can only input one number.  There could be multiple lines on the graph, and in this case more than one y value would be output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How's your algebra?

There's actually an example of this buried in flot's examples [here](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/tracking/index.html). If you view the source to that page you'll see this (I've added explanation comments):

```
// Find the nearest points, x-wise
// loop the series data until you find the point
// immediately after your x value of interest (pos.x in this code)
for (j = 0; j < series.data.length; ++j) {
    if (series.data[j][0] > pos.x) {
        break;
    }
}

// Now Interpolate
// Here's the algebra fun!
var y,
    p1 = series.data[j - 1], // point before your x
    p2 = series.data[j]; // point after your x

if (p1 == null) {
    y = p2[1]; // if no point before just get y-value
} else if (p2 == null) {
    y = p1[1]; // if no point after just get y-value
} else {
    y = p1[1] + (p2[1] - p1[1]) * (pos.x - p1[0]) / (p2[0] - p1[0]);
    // here's the algebra bit, see below    
}
```

In that final else the equation used is [this interpolation between two points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation#Linear_interpolation_between_two_known_points).  Ain't math grand?